# how to know whether service is running or not

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-service, alarmmanager

I am starting my service through alarmManager.I want to show a dialog box as soon as service gets start.How can I do it? I mean how to know whether my service started or not.Is there any capability in alarmmanager to let me know when it triggers its event or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to show a dialog box as soon as service gets start.How can I do it?

Please don't. First, services cannot display a `Dialog`. Second, users really do not like random windows popping up in the middle of their doing other work, playing games, etc.

> I mean how to know whether my service started or not.

Use LogCat and `android.util.Log`.

> Is there any capability in alarmmanager to let me know when it triggers its event or something like that.

Use LogCat and `android.util.Log` in your `Service` (or, if applicable, in the `BroadcastReceiver` that starts the `Service`).

Answer (score 0):

You could send a broadcast when the service starts, and receive it somewhere else to show the dialog.